# bash outputting empty array as empty string

Tags: arrays, bash

This has been asked several times, with several accepted answers, but, on my trials none of the answers seem to work...  I have two arrays, each of which represent the parameter list for a command.  As such, I want to quote the strings properly to use with eval:

```
bash-4.2> ARRAY0=()
bash-4.2> ARRAY3=("ONE" "TWO WITH SPACE" "THREE")
bash-4.2> echo cmd $opt_arg $(printf "%q " "${ARRAY0[@]}")
cmd ''
bash-4.2> echo cmd $opt_arg $(printf "%q " "${ARRAY3[@]}")
cmd ONE TWO\ WITH\ SPACE THREE
bash#
```

Where `$opt_arg` may or may not be populated.  The problem is that in the first case, where the array is empty, it outputs `''` as a parameter, even though the array is empty.  This kills my command, as it's expecting zero arguments.   I've not found a neat solution (I can do an `if [[ ${#ARRAY0[@]} ]]` around it, but that's rather ugly...).   Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: What is the `dash` tag doing in a question about arrays? dash doesn't support arrays at all (nor does it support `printf '%q'`).

Comment: And btw, `[[ ${#array[@]} ]]` doesn't work -- it checks for whether your string is empty. `0` is no more an empty string than `1` is.

Comment: Also, be sure you quote your expansions. In that context, that means `echo "cmd $opt_arg $( (( ${#array[@]} )) && printf '%q ' "${array[@]}")"`

Comment: (BTW, is there any reason your `opt_arg` isn't part of the array, or even a separate array? That way you could have multiple optional arguments if you wanted to without needing unquoted expansion).

Comment: Yes, the source of the array and the opt_arg come from different places.   I was considering adding to a single array, though it's just as ugly as everything else.  I'm considering moving the array to a string at this point (and converting to a dash script)

Comment: Difficult to do without security risks if you don't trust your data (converting to dash without reducing the set of data your code can correctly process, that is to say). That said, if you have a Python runtime available, *that* has a shell-escaping routine you can use easily enough that will substitute for `printf %q` while being fully compatible with dash. I've written a shell function that calls into the Python `pipes.quote` routine on this site a few times, when a question called for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom I use for this is to always check array length:

```
(( ${#array[@]} )) && printf '%q ' "${array[@]}"
```

That said, in present case, you can avoid the zero-argument case simply by having your `cmd` in the list, ensuring that `printf` always has at least one non-format-string argument:

```
printf '%q ' cmd "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `printf`? Just `"${ARRAY0[@]}"` should be fine.

```
for i in cmd $opt_arg "${ARRAY0[@]}"; do echo "[[[$i]]]"; done
[[[cmd]]]

for i in cmd $opt_arg "${ARRAY3[@]}"; do echo "[[[$i]]]"; done
[[[cmd]]]
[[[ONE]]]
[[[TWO WITH SPACE]]]
[[[THREE]]]
```

Comment: `printf %q` generates an `eval`-safe version of its arguments. It's what you use when you want to generate code for use by another shell.

Comment: so, let's say you've got code like `run-remote-sandbox() { local cmd_q=; (( $# )) && printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$@"; ssh otherhost bash -s <<<"in-sandbox $cmd_q"; }`, where you trust the program `in-sandbox` to run absolutely any code safely. If someone invoked `run-remote-sandbox touch '/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)'`, `printf %q` will make sure that the remote copy of bash doesn't try to execute that command substitution *before* starting the sandbox, as it would have if you'd just `echo`'d the argument.

Comment: The question does not mention neither security nor remote execution with ssh. Give better example with say "ssh localhost"... You can always do the for loop and fill another array, right?

Comment: Sure, but why would the OP be using `%q` if they *didn't* have code-generation needs? That's what it's for.

Comment: ...but sure, glad to provide a use case that doesn't involve ssh: `run-in-an-hour() { printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"; at 'now + 1 hour' <<<"$cmd"; }`

Comment: That said, it's completely obvious that the OP *is* trying to generate a string which, when evaluated by a shell as code, will run a command (`cmd`) with a set of arguments from an array. That's what the original code in their question *does*, except in the case where the array is empty (where they get an empty argument injected).

Comment: `X=(); for i in cmd $opt_arg "${ARRAY3[@]}"; do X=("${X[@]}" $(printf "%q" "$i")); done; echo "${X[@]}"` results in `cmd ONE TWO\ WITH\ SPACE THREE`.

Comment: That works, but *damn* it's ugly. Every `$()` is a `mkfifo()`, a `fork()` and a `wait()`; they're not free, or even cheap. Much faster to use `printf -v` to print directly to a destination variable, and likewise to pass multiple arguments to a single call so you don't need to loop externally.

Comment: So... we are now optimizing? Try `printf "%q " cmd $opt_arg "${ARRAY3[@]}"`.

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine in the case where you have a fixed `cmd`. That said, I wouldn't describe this as "optimizing" so much as "not doing hideous things in the first place".

Comment: Thanks, you are so kind :-) I now know that for loops are hideous, ugly and so on... thanks a lot.